# Remove specific special character from multiple file names under windows folder using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have to remove the "%" character from multiple file names which are under multiple folders in microsoft windows os. I have tried below batch script but unable to do it. Can anyone guide me how achieve this.

```
@echo off &setlocal
cd /d C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\New folder
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *%*.*.*') do (
    set "fname=%%~a"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "nname=!fname:ø=!"
    ren "!fname!" "!nname!"
    endlocal
)
```

Below is the file folder & file structure, From these all folder & sub folder I have need to remove "%" from all the files which have that. files included in folders are having a different file extensions

[image]

[image]

Comment: In cmd.exe, and moreso in a batch file, `%` is a special character, and must be handled as such. Also, if `%` is your target character, why are you trying to replace `ø` characters instead?

Comment: To get a literal `%` symbol, you need to double it in a batch file…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this isn't exactly what you asked for, but if you're interested primarily in the result and not in the method, you should seriously consider a different tool, because CMD BAT honestly isn't a good fit for this job.

This Powershell one-liner does the trick. Just navigate a Powershell console to the affected root folder and fire this command:

```
dir -recurse | ?{ $_.name -like '*%*' } | %{ ren $_.fullname ( $_ -replace '%','' ) }
```